# Cannot initialize TimeSpan with a collection initializer in linq query ¿Syntax error?

Tags: c#, linq

I build a ViewModel from a linq query to entities and then I do the following foreach:

```
_result.ForEach(t => t.horarioiniAFSP = (from U in model.AsistenciaCurso
                                          join T in model.Parametros
                                          on U.IdCurso equals T.ValorNumerico
                                          where U.UserId.Equals(t.UserId)
                                          && T.NombreParametro == "Modulo1"
                                          select new TimeSpan
                                          {
                                          U.HorarioInicio
                                          }).ToList());
```

However I can't get rid of the error: "Cannot initialize System.TimeSpan with a collection initalizer because it does not implement IEnumerable.

What is wrong? I suspect its a matter of syntax but I can't figure it out, formerly I did this:

```
_result.ForEach(t => t.horariofinAFSP = model.AsistenciaCurso.Where(u => u.UserId.Equals(t.UserId)).Select(x => x.HorarioFin).ToList());
```

Which is ok because I'm using linq Select, but then I tried to do the Join with lambdas like this:

```
_result.ForEach(t => t.horarioiniAFSP.AddRange(model.AsistenciaCurso.Where(u => u.UserId.Equals(t.UserId)).Join(model.Parametros, id => id.IdCurso, num => num.ValorNumerico, (id, num) => new TimeSpan { id.HorarioInicio })));
```

But that triggers the same error about not being able to initialize with a collection. I really don't have the time to google to much about this so that's why I'm asking this question. Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the type of `HorarioInicio`?

Comment: Also, *I really don't have the time to google to much about this* is not a good reason to ask a question on stack overflow ...

Comment: In SQL server HorarioInicio is Time(0) and in C# it's a TimeSpan

Comment: Than `select u.HorarioInicio` should do the trick.

Comment: That's right, thank you, like I said, I suspected it's a matter of syntax because from what I have read it seems that error comes when you initialize a class without explicitly declaring it's properties, so this time there's no property to declare, right?

Comment: I know it's not good to be in such a hurry that there's no time to google it, but here in stack overflow people are with such experience that getting things straight can be really fast. I'm just grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I know the solution has been found; posting an answer because nobody else has bothered to do so)*

Like the error says, you can't initialize a TimeSpan with a collection initializer.

TimeSpan has [four different constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that you can choose from when creating a new one, but if you already have a timespan, then just use that:

```
from U in model.AsistenciaCurso
join T in model.Parametros
on U.IdCurso equals T.ValorNumerico
where U.UserId.Equals(t.UserId)
&& T.NombreParametro == "Modulo1"
select U.HorarioInicio
```

Comment: That's what I did, I expect you wan't to mark it as the answer. I'll do it, but credit goes to MarcinJuraszek for such a quick reply (just kiddin)

Comment: @gerardoflores You can do whatever you like. :) It's simply that if _nobody_ answers the question, then people will continue to come here because they think it's unsolved. If Marcin comes back and adds an answer, I encourage you to accept it, but I think at this point, he's unlikely to do that. :)